# jQuery - two .on('change') events are not working at the same time. Works only each at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a "worked hours" calculator for my family. I want to have a reusable JavaScript code for all the "Default work start time, default end time, and default break hours time".

I simply want to make a function that takes the ID of the  from each area whenever there is a change and assign the  value to the defaultStart, DefaultEnd, defaultBreak objects, depending the area they come from.

I am using dynamically generated  elements, so I don't have to write minutes and hours manually.

I have tried the following code :

```
// This is my object
     const defaultBreak = {
     hour: "0",
     minute: "0"
}
let currentFocus; // The currentFocus which changes its value whenever 
                     there is a change in document

// Gets the targeted ID and assigns to currentFocus
$(document).on('change', function (e) {
    currentFocus = `#` + e.target.id;
    console.log(`${currentFocus}`);
});

// Here comes my problem. 
// I want to have `${currentFocus}` as a variable, so later in the 
// code I can do 
// if (currentFocus == break-hours)
// {defaultBreak.hours = this.val();

$('.calculator__head').on('change', `${currentFocus}`, function () {
    alert($(this).val());

    // This will be changed to 'if else' later.
    defaultBreak.hour = $(this).val();
    // console.log(defaultBreak)
});
```

My HTML is

```
            <div class="calculator__head">
                <div class="calculator__head--default-times">
                    <div class="calculator__head--default-times--start">
                        <span>Default start time</span>
                        <div class="select-area">
                            <select id="default-hour-select-start">
                            </select>
                            <label for="default-hour-select-start">Hours</label>
                            <select id="default-minute-select-start">
                            </select>
                            <label for="default-minute-select-start">Minutes</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator__head--default-times--end">
                        <span>Default End time</span>
                        <div class="select-area">
                            <select id="default-hour-select-end">
                            </select>
                            <label for="default-hour-select-end">Hours</label>
                            <select id="default-minute-select-end">
                            </select>
                            <label for="default-minute-select-end">Minutes</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculator__head--default-times--break">
                        <span>Default Break time</span>
                        <div class="select-area">
                            <select id="default-hour-select-break">
                            </select>
                            <label for="default-hour-select-break">Hours</label>
                            <select id="default-minute-select-break">
                            </select>
                            <label for="default-minute-select-break">Minutes</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had the option to have any HTML structure, you could simplify it like the following example. Good structure will help you save time in the future when it comes to accessing items using [Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // This is for populating the values
  $('.calculator-head .default-times select').each(function() {
    var selectElement = $(this);

    if (selectElement.hasClass('hour')) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        selectElement.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
      }
    } else if (selectElement.hasClass('minute')) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        selectElement.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
      }
    }
  });


  $('.default-times select').on('change', function(e) {
    var myObj = {
      start: {
        hour: $('.default-times .start select.hour').val(),
        minute: $('.default-times .start select.minute').val()
      },
      end: {
        hour: $('.default-times .end select.hour').val(),
        minute: $('.default-times .end select.minute').val()
      },
      break: {
        hour: $('.default-times .break select.hour').val(),
        minute: $('.default-times .break select.minute').val()
      }
    }
    console.log(myObj);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator-head">
  <div class="default-times">
    <div class="start">
      <span>Default start time</span>
      <div class="select-area">
        <select title="Start Time Hours" class="hour"></select>
        <label class="hour">Hours</label>
        <select title="Start Time Minutes" class="minute"></select>
        <label class="minute">Minutes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="end">
      <span>Default End time</span>
      <div class="select-area">
        <select title="End Time Hours" class="hour"></select>
        <label class="hour">Hours</label>
        <select title="End Time Minutes" class="minute"></select>
        <label class="minute">Minutes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break">
      <span>Default Break time</span>
      <div class="select-area">
        <select title="Break Time Hours" class="hour"></select>
        <label class="hour">Hours</label>
        <select title="Break Time Minutes" class="minute"></select>
        <label class="minute">Minutes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for answering! Both of the answers were good. I just hope to get as good as you one day. 
@Attila Antal - thank you. Now I realize there is a better way of structuring things.

Answer (score -1):

I do not even think you need to keep track of that unless there is some other reason, BUT I put that in there as that is the question with `myApp.currentChange = {id: myId,value:myVal};`

Let's make this a bit more manageable for our demonstration here, let's create a `myApp` to hold the values and an array for hours and minutes so we can add the options from there for our demonstration code here.

I set a class on each of the `<select>` to make wiring it up easier.

Now we can simply check when element changed with a `switch` by sniffing the id and then setting the proper value.  This could also be something like `data-target="breakHour"` or some such to keep the ID's out of the mix here. This should simplify the entire thing a bit from an understanding and code perspective.

There is no validation here like for example your start should come before your end (it it is the same day), break should come between (do you need two breaks if it is a long shift?) etc.  I will leave that exercise to you as it is not part of the question.

```js
var myApp = myApp || {
  break: {
    hour: 0,
    minute: 0
  },
  start: {
    hour: 0,
    minute: 0
  },
  end: {
    hour: 0,
    minute: 0
  },
  defaultHours: [...Array(24).keys()],
  defaultMinutes: [...Array(60).keys()],
  setupOptions: function(selector, values) {
    let $el = $(selector);
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      let opt = "<option value='" + values[i] + "'>" + values[i] + "</option>";
      $el.append(opt);
    }
  }
};
$(function() {
  // this could be in a loop by putting the ID's in an array or something also
  myApp.setupOptions("#default-hour-select-start", myApp.defaultHours);
  myApp.setupOptions("#default-minute-select-start", myApp.defaultMinutes);
  myApp.setupOptions("#default-hour-select-end", myApp.defaultHours);
  myApp.setupOptions("#default-minute-select-end", myApp.defaultMinutes);
  myApp.setupOptions("#default-hour-select-break", myApp.defaultHours);
  myApp.setupOptions("#default-minute-select-break", myApp.defaultMinutes);

  $('.calculator__head')
    .on('change', '.my-select-thing', function(event) {
      let me = $(this);
      let myId = me.attr("id");
      let myVal = me.val();
      myApp.currentChange = {id: myId,value:myVal};
      //alert(myVal);
      //console.log(myVal);
      //what changed:
      switch (myId) {
        case "default-hour-select-start":
          myApp.start.hour = myVal;
          break;
        case "default-minute-select-start":
          myApp.start.minute = myVal;
          break;
        case "default-hour-select-break":
          myApp.break.hour = myVal;
          break;
        case "default-minute-select-break":
          myApp.break.minute = myVal;
          break;
        case "default-hour-select-end":
          myApp.end.hour = myVal;
          break;
        case "default-minute-select-end":
          myApp.end.minute = myVal;
          break;
        default:
          console.log('Sorry, I did not set up ' + meId);
      }
      // just to show it changing
      $('#what-changed').html("<span>Id:" +  myApp.currentChange.id + " val:" +  myApp.currentChange.value + "</span>");
    });
});
```

```css
#what-changed {
  border: solid 1px #EEEEEE;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator__head">
  <div class="calculator__head--default-times">
    <div class="calculator__head--default-times--start">
      <span>Default start time</span>
      <div class="select-area">
        <select class="my-select-thing" id="default-hour-select-start">
        </select>
        <label for="default-hour-select-start">Hours</label>
        <select class="my-select-thing" id="default-minute-select-start">
        </select>
        <label for="default-minute-select-start">Minutes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calculator__head--default-times--end">
      <span>Default End time</span>
      <div class="select-area">
        <select class="my-select-thing" id="default-hour-select-end">
        </select>
        <label for="default-hour-select-end">Hours</label>
        <select class="my-select-thing" id="default-minute-select-end">
        </select>
        <label for="default-minute-select-end">Minutes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calculator__head--default-times--break">
      <span>Default Break time</span>
      <div class="select-area">
        <select class="my-select-thing" id="default-hour-select-break">
        </select>
        <label for="default-hour-select-break">Hours</label>
        <select class="my-select-thing" id="default-minute-select-break">
        </select>
        <label for="default-minute-select-break">Minutes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="what-changed">&nbsp;</div>
```